# SUPEE-6788 Patch CMS Pro News/Blog by MageWorld not working

Tags: controllers, security, admin-controller, patches

I'm preparing my Magento module config.xml file for SUPEE-6788 security patch, following this post
http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details
According to this post, I need to update

```
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <cmspro_admin>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>MW_Cmspro</module>
                    <frontName>cmspro_admin</frontName>
                </args>
            </cmspro_admin>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

I have updated to

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <cmspro_admin after="Mage_Adminhtml">MWCmsproAdmin_Adminhtml</cmspro_admin>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

However, when I click on the navbar to add news, it just takes me to the home page, I think I don't have any admin permission maybe?
Could anyone point out what I have done wrong?

Comment: What homepage would that be¿ Admin homepage or front-end?

Comment: homepage, I mean the shop front-end.

Comment: Ok we've seen this several times now and the issue is, that you have only updated the module XML, but you have not moved the controllers accordingly not renamed them and references to them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update all the references which call your controller(s).

Talking about the "navbar" you need to check and update how you call your newley added pages via `system.xml`.

Also you shoud check `getUrl()` and `_redirect()` function calls for the right routing paths.